# Splunk: Different color on one bar-graph

Tags: logging, graph, splunk

In my application i am trying display logs from logger.
So my source structure:

`Application` - application name 
`Interface` - logger name 
`Level` - log level

My search query :

```
index="log_index" sourcetype=log_source
| eval logger = Application + ":" + Interface + " - " + Level 
| eval error= if(Level == "Error", 1, 0) 
| eval warn= if(Level == "Warn", 1, 0) 
| eval info= if(Level == "Info", 1, 0) 
| eval fatal= if(Level == "Fatal", 1, 0)
| search fatal=1 OR error=1 OR warn=1 OR info=0
| stats count(Level) by logger sort by count(Level) desc
```

I set my options as:

```
<option name="charting.axisLabelsX.majorLabelStyle.overflowMode">ellipsisNone</option>
<option name="charting.axisLabelsX.majorLabelStyle.rotation">0</option>
<option name="charting.axisTitleX.visibility">visible</option>
<option name="charting.axisTitleY.visibility">visible</option>
<option name="charting.axisTitleY2.text">title</option>
<option name="charting.axisTitleY2.visibility">visible</option>
<option name="charting.axisX.scale">linear</option>
<option name="charting.axisY.scale">linear</option>
<option name="charting.axisY2.enabled">0</option>
<option name="charting.axisY2.scale">inherit</option>
<option name="charting.chart">bar</option>
<option name="charting.chart.bubbleMaximumSize">500</option>
<option name="charting.chart.bubbleMinimumSize">10</option>
<option name="charting.chart.bubbleSizeBy">area</option>
<option name="charting.chart.nullValueMode">gaps</option>
<option name="charting.chart.showDataLabels">minmax</option>
<option name="charting.chart.sliceCollapsingThreshold">0.01</option>
<option name="charting.chart.stackMode">default</option>
<option name="charting.chart.style">shiny</option>
<option name="charting.drilldown">all</option>
<option name="charting.layout.splitSeries">1</option>
<option name="charting.layout.splitSeries.allowIndependentYRanges">0</option>
<option name="charting.legend.labelStyle.overflowMode">ellipsisMiddle</option>
<option name="charting.legend.placement">right</option>
<option name="charting.chart">column</option>
<option name="charting.chart.stackMode">stacked</option>
<option name="charting.fieldColors">{"error":0xFF0000,"warn":0xFFFF00, "info":0x73A550, "fatal": 0x000000}</option>
<option name="charting.seriesColors">[0xFF0000,0xFFFF00,0x00FF00, 0x000000]</option>
```

My aim:
I would like to match bar color to level for each logger (application plus interface plus level). So bar with level fatal should be red, error black etc etc.

I hope someone of you will know how to configure that tool.

Answer (score 0):

complex solution :

[splunk answer](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/424520/different-color-on-one-bar-graph.html) 
`by somesoni2 from splunk answer`

copied content:

```
index="log_index" sourcetype=log_source 
Level="Error" OR Level="Warn" OR Level="Info" OR Level="Fatal" 
| eval logger = Application + ":" + Interface 
| chart count over logger by Level
| addtotals  
| sort -Total 
| fields - Total
```